# Using malliavin derivative to find the worst Delta-positive hedge?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, delta-hedging, delta-neutral, malliavin-calculus

### Background:

I've heard that Malliavin Calculus can be used to show the explicit form of a delta-neutral hedge (given an SDE driven market model).  For example, here is a sketch [here](https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/bayerc/files/hedging.pdf) on page 21 on how to achieve a $\Delta$-neutral hedge but how would one achieve a $\Delta$-positive hedge.

### Question:

Fix $T>0$.
My question is how can this proof strategy be used to show the existence of a hedge $H$ which has:

- positive Delta throughout $[0,T]$
- H(0)=1
- $\Delta H(T)\geq \Delta \tilde{H}(T)$ for every hedge $\tilde{H}$ with $\tilde{H}(0)=1$.

Comment: What you are asking is unclear to me: in what respect would that be a $Delta$ hedge if $Delta$ is not zero?

Comment: By a hedge I mean an admissible strategy; a progressively measurable map wrt the SDE process $X_t$ modeling the market